# WSO2 EI, grouping sequences into folders

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I'm currently integrating some services via WSO2 EI and because of having a lot of methods, I have created a lot of sequences:

[image]

There are more than forty sequences in my project and there will be more.

Is it possible to somehow group these sequences in folders, they are not dynamic and won't be saved in registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have different ESB projects and composite applications based on your usecase to group the artifacts (e.g. Sequences). Please refer the best practices guide in [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Best+Practices#BestPractices-Creatingartifacts).

Comment: You mean multiple esb solution projects in one workspace?

Comment: Yes. you can have multiple esb projects in one workspace.